# Most efficient way to create lower resolution texture from a texture in Metal?

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I have a large MTLTexture (up to 16k) that I need to create a lower resolution texture from - say half or quarter scale.

I can draw the high res texture into a lower resolution texture with:

```
let descriptorSmallerCanvas = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
descriptorSmallerCanvas.colorAttachments[0].texture = canvasTextureSmaller
descriptorSmallerCanvas.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .store
descriptorSmallerCanvas.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .clear
let renderSmallCanvas = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: descriptorSmallerCanvas)
renderSmallCanvas?.pushDebugGroup("Render Small Texture")
renderSmallCanvas?.setRenderPipelineState(renderCanvasPipelineState)
renderSmallCanvas?.setFragmentTexture(canvasTexture, index: 0)
renderSmallCanvas?.setVertexBuffer(uniformOrthoBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
renderSmallCanvas?.setCullMode(.none)
renderSmallCanvas?.drawPrimitives(type: .triangleStrip, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: 4, instanceCount: 1)
renderSmallCanvas?.popDebugGroup()
renderSmallCanvas?.endEncoding()
```

That works, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this? Would `MTLBlitCommandEncoder`'s `generateMipmaps(for: canvasTexture)` be more efficient, or is there a more efficent way?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the algorithm you want to downscale with.

Without knowing what `renderCanvasPipelineState`  is, I would guess that it renders a fullscreen quad that  Rendering larger texture into smaller texture will use `minFilter` of the sampler state you have in your shader (I guess it's a `constexpr` sampler since you don't bind any here) so it would only use `MTLSamplerMinMagFilterLinear` at best, which isn't "high-quality" downscaling.

I think your best bet without writing your own resize is to use [MPSImageLanczosScale](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalperformanceshaders/mpsimagelanczosscale?language=objc) or [MPSImageBilinearScale](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalperformanceshaders/mpsimagebilinearscale?language=objc)
 depending on the quality tradeoffs you want to make.

P.S. You don't need to `.clear` your attachment if you are filling the whole screen without blending, leave it at `.dontCare` and it will overwrite every pixel.